# Find integral values of x , y and z : $6x +10y + 15z= -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm, linear-diophantine-equations

I have done similar type of questions before by using the Euclidean Division Lemma/Algorithm to rewrite the equation and then find the solution, but those were problems with only two variables.

In the above equation, as there are three variables, I am confused on how to proceed. Here's what I have tried till now -

$6x + 10y + 15z = -1$

$10y + 3(2x+5z) = -1$

Let $2x+5z = m$. Then, we have $10y + 3m = -1$

For the above equation, we have integral solutions as $y=1$ and $m=-3$.

$2x + 5y = -3$

I am stuck here and unable to find integral solution for x, y. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already have $y=1$ so $x=-4$...

Comment: if $a,b$ are coprime integers there always exists integers $x,y$ s.t ax+by = 1 (see Bezout's lemma)

Comment: @abiessu How did you get $x= -4$ from $y = 1$?

Comment: $2x+5y=-3$ but the previous solution restricts $y=1$ so then $2x+5=-3$ or $2x=-8$...

Comment: What about $x=1$ and $z=-1$? (It should be $z$, not $y$)

Comment: @MahammadYusifov I have used Bezout's lemma in previous questions, but they only had two variables. How do you use the lemma for 3?

Comment: Oh, yes, the variable mixing is what messed that up.  $z=-1, x=1$ works great.

Comment: @Dominique Thanks! That works! If there is 1 integral solution, there should be a general form too, right?

Comment: find all $(y,m)$ pairs , then find all $(x,z)$ pairs giving that $m$.

Comment: @MahammadYusifov Thanks! I think I can take it from here.

Comment: $y=-1+3k,m=3-10k$ (your "$y=1$ and $m=-3$" is wrong) and then $x=-2m+5\ell,z=m-2\ell$.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Shouldn't that be an answer instead of a comment? :-)

Comment: I am sure @BillDubuque will soon close as a duplicate, with the appropriate links.